# Cloning existing Slack Application

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to duplicate an existing Slack App with only some minor configuration changes.

Is there an easier way to do this other than creating a new slack app from scratch and configuring it all over again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use the **App Manifest** feature. On your app page, click App Manifest and copy over the YAML/JSON from the main app to the new app. This approach will copy over things like scopes and common app configurations.

More info [here](https://api.slack.com/reference/manifests)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right no, now, you can only use the UI to create and configure apps, which doesn't have a "duplicate app" feature. But an App Config API is currently on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/g7IwQxY0) and you'll be able to use that to download an existing configuration, tweak as needed and create a new app based on it.